# Snowflake match_recognize not including all instances of a given pattern using quantifiers

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, match-recognize

I'm trying to use Snowflake's match_recognize tool to match a particular pattern across rows.  The pattern consists of any sequence of a's and b's, provided that long runs of b's are excluded.  In my test case, I want to allow runs of up to 4 b's to be included in the match.

Using the handy https://regexr.com/?2tp0k website, I was able to build the desired regexp:

`((ab{0,4})+a)|a+`

Applying it to this string:

*baabbbaaaaaaaababbabbabbabbbabbbab*

I get this one match (in bold), which I am happy with:

*b**aabbbaaaaaaaababbabbabbabbbabbba**b*

As desired, this is absorbing into the match any run of b's that is 4 or shorter. (It doesn't pick up *b* at the beginning of the string or the *b* at the end, but that is expected.) Also note that while it doesn't contain any long runs of b's, there are a bunch of b's spread throughout that match.

For some reason, when I use this regular expression with Snowflake's match_recognize pattern, it doesn't take up all of the short runs of b's.

Hence, instead of matching the entire sequence matched above, it matches these:

*b**aabbbaaaaaaaababbabbabba**bbb**abbba**b*

Any suggestions?

Here's the query that illustrates the result:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
     ( 0,'b'),( 1,'a'),( 2,'a'),( 3,'b'),( 4,'b'),( 5,'b'),( 6,'a'),( 7,'a'),( 8,'a'),( 9,'a'),
     (10,'a'),(11,'a'),(12,'a'),(13,'a'),(14,'b'),(15,'a'),(16,'b'),(17,'b'),(18,'a'),(19,'b'),
     (20,'b'),(21,'a'),(22,'b'),(23,'b'),(24,'a'),(25,'b'),(26,'b'),(27,'b'),(28,'a'),(29,'b'),
     (30,'b'),(31,'b'),(32,'a'),(33,'b')
)
SELECT * FROM data 
match_recognize(
    order by column1
    measures
        match_number() as "MATCH_NUMBER",
        match_sequence_number() as msq,
        classifier() as cl
    all rows per match with unmatched rows
    PATTERN ( ((a b{0,4})+ a) | a+ )
    DEFINE
        a as column2 = 'a',
        b as column2 = 'b'
)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Resulting in this result.  Rows 25-27 are not included in the match, and a new match is started at row 28.

[Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etDCP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
 ( 0,'b'),( 1,'a'),( 2,'a'),( 3,'b'),( 4,'b'),( 5,'b'),( 6,'a'),( 7,'a'),( 8,'a'),( 9,'a'),
 (10,'a'),(11,'a'),(12,'a'),(13,'a'),(14,'b'),(15,'a'),(16,'b'),(17,'b'),(18,'a'),(19,'b'),
 (20,'b'),(21,'a'),(22,'b'),(23,'b'),(24,'a'),(25,'b'),(26,'b'),(27,'b'),(28,'a'),(29,'b'),
 (30,'b'),(31,'b'),(32,'a'),(33,'b')
)
SELECT * FROM data  
match_recognize(
    order by column1
    measures
        match_number() as "MATCH_NUMBER",
        match_sequence_number() as msq,
        classifier() as cl
 all rows per match  with unmatched rows
AFTER MATCH SKIP  PAST LAST ROW
PATTERN ( ((a+ b{1,4})+ a) | a+ )
DEFINE
    a as column2 = 'a',
    b as column2 = 'b'
) ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Well, this modification does appear to work!  Do you have an understanding why this one would work and the former would not?  (For what it's worth, I think someone from Snowflake is looking into this.)

Comment: Short = Regex typo. Just added '+' to the first a.  Long = Your original regex enforced a single 'a' at the start of the match and unlimited 'a's at the end.  When there was a single 'a' between the b's it was forced to be part of the previous match (as you skip past last row). a+ b{1,4})+ a vs a b{1,4})+ a.   Just needed fresh eyes :-)

Comment: Please stop the Snowflake person -> we don't really want them tinkering with things - this was simply a typo in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough when changing pattern from `((ab{0,4})+a)|a+` to `( ((a | ab | abb | abbb | abbbb)+ a) | a+ )` it produces:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
     ( 0,'b'),( 1,'a'),( 2,'a'),( 3,'b'),( 4,'b'),( 5,'b'),( 6,'a'),( 7,'a'),( 8,'a'),( 9,'a'),
     (10,'a'),(11,'a'),(12,'a'),(13,'a'),(14,'b'),(15,'a'),(16,'b'),(17,'b'),(18,'a'),(19,'b'),
     (20,'b'),(21,'a'),(22,'b'),(23,'b'),(24,'a'),(25,'b'),(26,'b'),(27,'b'),(28,'a'),(29,'b'),
     (30,'b'),(31,'b'),(32,'a'),(33,'b')
)
SELECT * FROM data 
match_recognize(
    order by column1
    measures
        match_number() as "MATCH_NUMBER",
        match_sequence_number() as msq,
        classifier() as cl
    all rows per match with unmatched rows
    PATTERN ( ((a | ab | abb | abbb | abbbb)+ a) | a+ )
    DEFINE
        a as column2 = 'a',
        b as column2 = 'b'
)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is interesting, though in my actual case, I'm wanting to include runs of up to 59 (e.g. ((ab{0,59})+a)|a+ ).  I just used up to 4 to make a functional test case.